# How to allocate memory dynamically for a struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

I have a struct which has an array of another struct inside its.

```
typedef struct info_single {
    pid_t pidx;
    int type;
} info_single;

struct shared_info {
    long indexx;
    struct info_single single_info[];
};
```

The size of the array is given by the user. How do I allocate the memory through a `malloc`?
This is my solution but i don't know if it is correct

```
struct shared_info * data;
data = malloc(sizeof(*data)+n*sizeof(info_single));
```

Comment: What have you tried? How that failed?

Comment: A two-step allocation? the first one for `shared_info`, the second for the desired number of `info_single`s.

Comment: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.._

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: This is correct for me, but maybe use FMA for a beginner is a little hard... you could do the following too `data = malloc(sizeof *data + sizeof data->single_info * n);`

Comment: In this way can i do something like: data->single_info[0].type = 1 ?

Comment: @JimBelushi2 yes.

Comment: The question is now good, but it is still a duplicate. Upvoted